# Apples Magic Mouse and pressing left and right buttons together?

Tags: magic-mouse, mouse-buttons

How can I use left and right buttons together with the Apple Magic Mouse?
More exact press right button and then left button also?

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of.  The mouse is one big button and it knows when you raise your finger to right click.  This would mean if you were to press both fingers it would initiate a left click and not a left AND right click.

I could be wrong but, this is one of the main reasons why the Magic Mouse are fairly horrible when it comes to gaming.

Comment: There are **many** reasons the magic mouse sucks for gaming (it is great in other areas, though).

Answer (score 0):

There is a program that can enable this (and some other cool stuff): http://magicprefs.com/

When the two mouse button functionality is enabled, it's pretty hard to use in regular apps, because you have to hold your right finger off the mouse, which is uncomfortable. I don't know if it would be as uncomfortable in games. I just use a different mouse for gaming.